# Command prompt script is not accepting shared folder path in SQL Jobs

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file

I set up a SQL Job. As part of step # 1, batch script has to connect the folder and pick the file.

However, i am facing the error " The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. "

Folder path is correct. If i ran the same .bat file from Command Prompt, it is running successfully by moving the file.

```
Message
Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. C:\Windows\system32>move \\SharedNetwork\Inbound\*.* F:\FileImport\Inbound   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.  Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed.
```

Comment: Why are you doing this from SQL Server Agent? I would just use a Powershell job and/or Powershell called from a Windows task scheduler job. Much easier for server and file system to call into SQL Server than the opposite.

Comment: SQL Job has 3 steps. Step 1 is to move the file from shared folder to working folder. step 2 has import process. step 3 has report generation part. This all part of SQL Job Steps

Comment: Same batch file works fine.. when i execute directly or from command prompt

Comment: Yep. A SQL Server Agent job, however, does not run as you, and does not have the same permissions as you. Again, why does this have to be a SQL Server Agent job? If you have a batch file working, why do you need to involve SQL Server in this at all? Moving files and all this stuff just doesn't seem to be the right thing to put into a SQL Server Agent job.

Comment: Doing so will be all part of one job.Easy to maintain and monitor

Comment: I could ask the garbage man to mow my lawn, it would be easier to monitor both tasks if the same person is doing it. I just may not be happy with the results.

Comment: Thats the design given to me. I will have to work as per the requirement. Is there a way to fix the issue?

Comment: If @AaronBertrand says do not use SQL Server to do this, then do not use SQL Server to do this.

Comment: what is "F:"? Is this a mapped drive?

Comment: F: is not a mapped drive. It is actual disk partition  drive